# Distance-based sequential clustering for large data

Tags: clustering, python, large-data

Let's say I have a sequence of data point $x_1,\dots, x_n\in \Bbb R^d$. I would like to build clusters as follows: I give some $\varepsilon$, and start with $x_1$. At each step $k$ I add $x_{k+1}$ to the previous cluster if it is within $\varepsilon$ distance from some point from that cluster, otherwise I start a new cluster (and close the old one).

I am working in Python, and I don't know of any package that can do this job, so I am going to program this myself. A greedy way is to run over all points in the current cluster to find the closest one, but maybe there is a more efficient way? Say, somehow keep track of "boundary" points of the cluster, and only compare distance to them? I will only have to do this once, so precomputing all the $n\times n$ distance matrix does not seem to be a good solution. FWIW, in my case $n \geq 10^5$ and I am doing this on a strong but usual machine, not a computational server.

Comment: The only issue I see with keeping track of boundaries of your cluster is that doing so would require to iterate over all the points in your cluster anyway to know whether the new point is pushing a boundary or is sitting within the cluster. You might have better luck using cluster centroids rather than keeping track of all the points in each cluster.

Comment: Do some more research on the existing approaches. This sounds like a simplified version of SLINK, which is closely related to minimum spanning trees. The "boundary" is not enough to keep - how would you detect the "inside"? But a good index will help you: find the nearest neighbor of the existing points if it is closer than eps.